# Display Current Time using Fragment in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, fragment

I am currently working on displaying current time on my Android application. I already got the current time but I need it to be dynamic; it should update every second. I have found this solution but there's something wrong:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Thread timerThread = null;

    Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
    timerThread = new Thread(runnable);
    timerThread.start();
}

public void doWork() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Date dt = new Date();
                int day = dt.getDate();
                int month = dt.getMonth();
                int hours = dt.getHours();
                int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                time.setText(curTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
}

class CountDownRunner implements Runnable {
    // @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                doWork();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on this line:

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {`

I think the reason for this error is because I'm implementing it in Fragment. It does not extend to an Activity which is necessary to implement Thread.

I tried to search and found a possible answer wherein I should need an activity to extend it on **runOnUiThread** but I haven't found any implementation how to do it. I'm somehow confused and stucked at the moment.

Comment: This might help you implement it better. This is a source code of official Android TextClock : https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextClock.java

Comment: Wow. This is awesome info. I will check on this. Thanks @Milanix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable...`

It's because:

1) the implicit this in your call to **runOnUiThread** is referring to **AsyncTask,** not your **fragment**.

2) **Fragment** doesn't have **runOnUiThread**

Answer (score 1):

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fragment then try to use:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
}
```

And if you are using this in Activity then use:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
}
```